# Programação funcional: aplicabilidade dos parâmetros (.x) e (.) em purrr::map

Tags: r, programação-funcional

Estou a migrar para o *package* `purrr`, principalmente em relação ao uso da função `map`. Mas, estou com muita dificuldade de entender os conceitos de programação funcional no `purrr`.

Gostaria de aprender a aplicar os parâmetros `(.x)` e `(.)` dentro de `map`, em vez de usar o `function(x)` com a família `apply`.

Mais precisamente,

- em quais contextos usar `(.x)` e `(.)`?
- `(.x)` e `(.)` são substitutos definitivos de `function(x)`?
- como usar `(.x)` e `(.)` em outros *packages* e funções, como `dplyr::mutate`?

Para demonstrar a minha dificuldade, tento a horas escrever a função a seguir em um `map` com `(.x)` e `(.)`, a qual só consigo com `function(x)`:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(1:10,function(x){
  names<-str_c('var',x)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100),envir=.GlobalEnv)
})
```

Já tentei várias configurações com `map` e `(.x)` e `(.)`, mas só são geradas mensagens de erro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As funções do `purrr` possuem a seguinte sintaxe:

```
map(vetor_ou_lista, funcao)
```

Em seguida o que ele faz é aplicar a `funcao` para cada elemento do `vetor_ou_lista`.

`funcao` pode ser qualquer função do R ou uma função anônima, como no seu exemplo.

#### Funções anônimas como fórmulas

No entanto, o `purrr` fornece uma sintaxe alternativa para criar funções anônimas.

Essa sintaxe funciona da seguinte forma:

```
map(vetor_ou_lista, ~mean(.x + 2))
```

Nesse caso, a fórmula `~mean(.x +2))` é equivalente a usar como argumento uma função assim:

```
function(.x) {
  mean(.x + 2)
}
```

> **Note** o **`~`** é importante para indicar que você está usando a sintaxe alternativa.Isso tem a ver com o `purrr`.

#### O caso do `.`

Já o `.` vem por em geral usarmos o  operador pipe (`%>%`). Por padrão o pipe passa o objeto que está a esquerda como primeiro argumento da função que está a sua direita, mas podemos mudar este comportamento usando o `.`, por exemplo:

```
TRUE %>% mean(x = 1:10, na.rm = .)
```

No caso acima estamos passando o `.` (`TRUE`) para o argumento `na.rm` da função `mean`.

Um outro comportamento interessante e pouco intuitivo é que se você usar o . dentro de uma chamada aninhada dentro da função da direita, ele ainda irá usar o objeto da esquerda como primeiro argumento da direita. Por exemplo:

```
1:10 %>% cor(y  = rev(.))
#> -1
```

Veja que neste caso ele calcula a correlação de x com rev(x) o que não teria ocorrido se fizéssemos:

```
1:10 %>% cor(y  = .)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Sendo assim, podemos usar esse comportamento também com o purrr, já que o `map` é uma função do R como qualquer outra. Isso então pode funcionar:

```
mtcars %>% keep(names(.) %in% c("gear", "carb"))
```

Veja que aqui, não uso `~`, já que estou retornando um vetor de TRUE e FALSE's.

#### A sua função

No caso da sua função, acho que o ideal seria fazer algo assim:

```
1:10 %>% 
  str_c("var", .) %>% 
  map(~assign(.x, runif(30,20,100),envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

#### Outros pacotes

A partir da versão 0.8.0 do `dplyr` (que ainda não foi para o CRAN, mas está no Github) você poderá usar essa sintaxe nas funções `mutate_*`, `summarise_*`, etc.

Na versão 0.8 você pode fazer isso, por exemplo:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(c("cyl", "gear"), ~.x + 1e6)
```

Até as versões anteriores, o jeito do `dplyr` era um pouco diferente pois usava a função `funs`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear), funs(. + 1e6))
```